# Как обозначить такой формат даты?

Tags: vue.js, date-fns

использую "vue good table". Для анализа дат "vue good table" использует "date-fns" Есть столбец "дата", который имеет свойство:
"dateInputFormat" - указывает формат даты, который должен быть у данных прилетающих с сервера,
и
"dateOutputFormat" - указывает формат даты, который будет выведен пользователю.
С сервера прилетает запись в которой дата указана как - "2021-06-01 22:55:20.913".
В коде я указываю формат 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', однако данные в таблице не отображаются, а в консоли появляется ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Какой формат тогда надо указывать?

```js
            {
              label: 'Дата',
              field: 'createdAt',
              type: 'date',
              dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
              dateOutputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
            }
```

Мне прилетает запись, в которой дата записана как - "2021-06-01 22:55:20.913".

Comment: `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'`

Comment: Спасибо,вы очень помогли).
А не подскажите почему yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS работает , а yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss нет?

Comment: Все, понял почему. Смотрю в книгу, как говорится.....

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Вместо этого

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Вы забыли добавить милисекунды в формат))